# calls to sign_up utility test method in utility.rb fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I'm sort of new to writing tests on Rails, and I'm following along with the RoR tutorial at http://ruby.railstutorial.org.  I'm trying to add my own test utility method, sign_up, similar to the sign_in method already in utility.rb.  When calling it against my sign up page, though, I get this error:

```
2) User pages index pagination as an admin user to unlock new users 
     Failure/Error: sign_up user
     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       cannot fill in, no text field, text area or password field with id, name, or label 'Name' found
     # (eval):2:in `fill_in'
     # ./spec/support/utilities.rb:33:in `sign_up'
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:63:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

My sign_up method looks like this:

```
def sign_up(user)
  visit signup_path
  fill_in "Name",         with: user.name
  fill_in "Email",        with: user.email
  fill_in "Password",     with: user.password
  fill_in "Confirmation", with: user.password
  click_button "Sign up"
end
```

It seems to start to go wrong even just visiting the signup_path - I'm not even sure it's going there.  Additionally, if I comment out the `fill_in "Name"` line, it will just choke on the `fill_in "Email"` line in the same way.

Any suggestions or ideas on what's going on here would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
-Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The light bulb finally went on.

When you create a user with the factory, it inserts it into the DB.  SO, when you go to the signup page and try to use that user it already exists **and you get redirected to the home page.  This means none of the fields exist to be used with fill_in**.  Simplified spec:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "signup page" do
  subject { page }

  describe "with valid information" do
    before { sign_up('em', 'em@em.com', '123456') }
    it { should have_title_and_h1('em') }
  end
end
```

utility method:

```
def sign_up(name, email, password)
  visit signup_path
  fill_in "Name",         with: name
  fill_in "Email",        with: email
  fill_in "Password",     with: password
  fill_in "Confirmation", with: password
  click_button "Create my account"
end
```

will create a user through the browser interface.